# Windows2003: A problem about installing Windows hotfix

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

If I install a hotfix like "http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?id=927579", is there any risk like something existing will be overriden or rolled back?

Please advise any concern on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a risk when installing any software that it could impact your existing systems, including hotifixes. You should be ensuring you have a full, good backup before you apply any hotfixes and have a plan in place should problems occur.

I would also recommend testing any hotfixes on a test system, that mirrors your live system, if you have one. If stability and uptime is important to you, then you should have one, and test all updates on here first.